# Cannot invoke value of type 'NSCalendar.Unit.Type' with argument list '(rawValue: UInt)'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, swift2

Aster Update my project from swift2.3 to swift 3 I got this error : Cannot invoke value of type 'NSCalendar.Unit.Type' with argument list '(rawValue: UInt)'
in swift3 NScalender renamed to Calendar but how to us calendar class in this code ?':

```
private func calendar(_ calendar: TKCalendar, eventsForDate date: Date) -> [AnyObject]? {
   let components = self.calendarView.calendar.component(NSCalendar.Unit(rawValue: NSCalendar.Unit.Year.rawValue|NSCalendar.Unit.Month.rawValue|NSCalendar.Unit.Day.rawValue), from: date)


    components.hour = 23
    components.minute = 59
    components.second = 59
    let endDate = self.calendarView.calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(startDate <= %@) AND (endDate >= %@)", endDate!, date)
    let result: NSArray = self.events.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
    return result as [AnyObject]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of swift 3 changes in Calendar class.

Change it to -

```
let components = self.calendarView.calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: date)
```